# Hitting enter in texbox calls a method

Tags: c#, methods, textbox

I have a textbox that when I type the value in, I want it to call a calculation method using that value. The method then displays the answer in a seperate label.

At the moment I have it set up with a default button to hit enter, but I have multiple buttons and don't always want to have to click them for an answer. Pressing enter to call a method would seem to work better if possible?

Here's my code:

```
private void btnCalculateL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CalLeg();
}

private void CalLeg()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtThroat.Text))
    {
        throatThickness = float.Parse(txtThroat.Text);
        legCal = 1.41421f * throatThickness;
        // throatThickness x leg / 1.41421
        lblAnswer.Text = legCal.ToString();
    }
    else
        lblAnswer.Text = "Please Enter a Value";
    // (throatThickness*legLength)/1.41421;
 }
```

Comment: What are you using? ASP.NET, WinForms, WPF?

Comment: see the textchanged event https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the `KeyDown` event of the textbox namely `txtThroat` like this:

```
private void txtThroat_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
  {
    CalLeg();
  }
}
```

Comment: I've pasted this segment into my code but pressing enter does not do anything. In my windows form setting for the textbox I have AcceptsReturn as True but still not working. When I click the button that calls for the method, that works fine.

Comment: @PaulCarson that is strange. can you debug and see when you press enter what actions are performed in `txtThroat_KeyDown` ?

Comment: Not too sure how to debug yet but I've set it to display text only to the label instead of a method and still nothing happens when enter is pressed?

Comment: Actually you will have to bind the event with the event handler. In InitializeComponent method, there should be a line like this `this.txtThroat.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.txtThroat_KeyDown);`

Comment: Perfect that fixed it. Thanks

Comment: @PaulCarson Please accept it as the answer. Thanks!